# How to update the Start and End positions of the specific Range after making changes to the document?

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, range, office-interop

I am creating a MS Office Word Add-in in C#. I need to get some information from the Document while working with it.

I take a certain `Range` of the document and save it.

For example, in the text:

> Text1 text2 ***text3*** text4

I save `Range` of the "text3". Its `Start` position = 13, `End` position = 17 (the number of characters, as I understand it).

If I change the text in front of this word:

> Text1 NEW TE ***XT te*** xt2 text3 text4

Positions of its `Range` will remain the same. When trying to select the text I get an incorrect text range.

**Is there a way to update the data of the `Range` object after editing the document?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range%28v=office.14%29.aspx) states:

> Each Range object is defined by a starting and ending character position

So what you assume:

> I save Range of the "text3". Its Start position = 13, End position = 17 (the number of characters, as I understand it).

... is correct.

> Positions of its Range will remain the same. When trying to select the text I get an incorrect text range.

I believe this is intended behavior, and I think it matches quite well what the documentation states about ranges here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range(v=office.14).aspx

> Is there a way to update the data of the Range object after editing
>   the document?

As far as I know, this is not possible, and as far as I can see, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range%28v=office.14%29.aspx) does not state that this should be possible either.

At first I thought that maybe a `Word` object existed encapsulating such functionality, [but it turns out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.words.aspx) that the `Words` collection on a document only contains `Ranges` that represents one word each - and that does not help much either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I agree with you. I continued to look for a solution to the problem, but I think that I need to write this algorithm manually. What I'm doing.